# System.BadImageFormatException - mismatch between versions

Tags: c#, reference

I am getting the following

> System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'Flir.Atlas.Live, Version=2.0.14266.1000, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=caa391fd8e07c76b' or one of its dependencies. An
> attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.'

I do have Flir.Atlas.Live referenced and the Version shows incorrectly as "2.0.14266.1000" in the reference properties.

[image]

When I go to the actual file I referenced at the path the version of that file is "6.0.18050.1001". When I check the dll file that is actually being copied to the bin/debug folder it is also version "6.0.18050.1001".

It is like there is a requirement somewhere that specifies version "2.0.14266.1000". I cannot find that version number anywhere in my solution when I search for it. If I delete Flir.Atlas.Live" as a reference and readd it I get the same result.

What could be causing the version mismatch?

**EDIT** - This is 64 bit. It was 32bit, I am compiling for 64 bit only.

**EDIT 2** - .csproj file has old version requirements:

```
<Reference Include="Flir.Atlas.Image, Version=2.0.14266.1000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=caa391fd8e07c76b, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\FLIR Systems\FLIR Atlas SDK 6\bin\x64\Flir.Atlas.Image.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Did you do a clean build?  There are intermediate obj files that may still have old reference.  Clean build should for the compiler to recompile the old files.

Comment: Is your application 32 bit or 64 bit? `BadImageFormatException` can be thrown if there is a mismatch in the architectures

Comment: @jdweng - Yes. I also deleted the bin/Debug and bin/release folders.

Comment: @mmathis - I edited my post to included information on bitness. Interestingly, the 32 bit version of the Flir.Atlas.Live also has version "6.0.18050.1001" as well.

Comment: Is version in the csproj file (open with notepad).  Do you have any dll or other projects referenced in project?

Comment: @jdweng - Sure is! That file is messed up. I will add the specific section to my post. Now how to eliminate the version requirement in a way that allows upgrading?

Comment: Delete the reference from the project in the Solution Explorer.  Then add the reference which should automatically add the correct version.  When you update Net to new version often the updating fails and leave a mess like this.  I suspect the reference object wasn't install when the project was updated to new version of Net.

Comment: @jdweng - I removed the references, saved the project, closed VS, reopened VS and the project and now the wrong versions are back in the vsproj file.

Comment: Does code run?  When you add the file VS is reading version.  When adding a reference you should select Add Existing and then browse to the DEBUG folder of project.  When you compile the compile will copy the dll to your project bin folder.  You should not put a dll manually into the bin.  then if you change type of project from Debug to Release the correct file will get copied to the right project folder.